# What is Facet design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

This question was asked during an interview to my friend. I searched on Google and found only [this](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FacetPattern) link. But this does not have much description. Can anyone explain preferably with a sample code?

Comment: I think this might be handy: http://www.hillside.net/plop/plop2002/final/plop2002_ecrahen0_0.pdf

Comment: Are you sure your friend hasn't been asked about the Facade pattern, not the Facet pattern?

Comment: I am sure Bv202, I guess he wanted to get rid of him. Tom Jonckheere, I think that might be the right answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Facet design Pattern- It restrict an interface to obtain a smaller interface that provides less authority. Means usually the smaller interface has only a subset of the methods, or allows only a subset of parameter values.
For example: Jdbc connector acts like Facet design.
 In Java, the interface JDBC can be called a facet. We as users or clients create connection using the “java.sql.Connection” interface, the implementation of which we are not concerned about. The implementation is left to the vendor of driver.